# JS не получается кликнуть кнопку

Tags: javascript, click

Игра https://monolife.ru/game/index.html?servernum=1 , нужно кликнуть по кнопке "Играть".

Делаю:

```
var game = document.getElementsByClassName("btn lobby-item__button");

var index;

for (index = 0; index < game.length; ++index) {

    game[index].click();

};
```

Не кликает, перебрал селекторы `btn lobby-item__button lobby-item__button--lock`,
`btn lobby-item__button lobby-item__view`, `btn lobby-item__button lobby-item__exit`,
по закрытой игре наживает, смотреть, выход тоже.
Пожалуйста подскажите решение.

Comment: А чё консоль ошибки выводит? 

Comment: ++index так разве можно записывать? может index++ ?

Comment: в консоли пусто, и когда  срабатывает нажатие на закрытую игру, и когда не срабатывает на открытую.

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы вам не проверить код отдельно... Это занимает всего 1 минуту. Код работает! Значит у вас ошибка в другом.

```js
var game = document.getElementsByClassName("btn lobby-item__button");

var index;

for (index = 0; index < game.length; ++index) {

    game[index].click();

};
```

```html
<button class="btn lobby-item__button" onclick="alert('button 1 clicked')">1</button>
<button class="btn lobby-item__button" onclick="alert('button 2 clicked')">2</button>
```